# How in the Hell do I get through Hell?

Tags: candy-box

I can't get through the waves of Demons at the start of Hell. I think I've managed it once with two invulnerability potions and an exceptionally lucky formation of demons that spawned randomly. I don't think I can count on that, which means there must be some easier way to get through all of this, especially after failing 25 times.

For reference, I'm using a Sword of Summoning (lvl 9), I have the Magic Horn and Plate Armor, and have 355 HP from having eaten more candy than an entire city of 9 year olds on November 1st.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you mean "What _the hell_ am I missing?"

Answer (score 19):

I suggest using only major healing potions for the first round, while directing yourself to the parts where the demon clusters are the thinnest. Use a major healing potion as soon as the cooldown is over, especially at the wall. What you want to aim for are single demons. Don't be afraid to hit those, since you have more than enough HP to survive.

Once you get teleported back, go to the bottom row as soon as possible and summon an imp. It will kill the ghosts as well as eat through a wall. On your final teleport back, go to the bottom row again (avoid fireballs whenever necessary) and summon another imp, which will cut through the hoard of ghosts to the demon. Use invincibility and spam fire scrolls, and you should be done.

Answer (score 6):

Use a scroll of imp summoning to deal with ghosts without losing health - an imp doesn't take damage from ghosts.

They do take damage from demons, so dodge and spam major healing potions, then in the second and third waves, summon a demon to be your shield, while making sure you heal up.

Use a potion of invuln to fight the devil at the end.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with all the answers. I found the best way to deal with wave one was with turtle potions. Of course you still need to dodge as much as possible, but the damage received from touching a demon is a lot less. 3 turtle potions did the trick with me. The downside is that you're a lot slower.

Next, when you get to the end of wave one, try to destroy the second block up from the bottom. This way you wont have to worry about banshees. Immediately drink a major potion at the start of wave two in case some of the demons remain. Line your self up with the broken wall and summon imps. Ghosts don't kill, they just reduce your health to like 10. So the imp will take all the damage and you will be safe. If you summon 3 imps, at the end of the wave, there will be no ghosts in that row. So when you respawn, you don't have to worry about being attacked by the previous wave.

In wave three, you have to use the same strategy as with wave 2. However, as you reach the wall, the ghosts turn to fireballs. This isn't that big a deal, but it may leave you vulnerable to the devil boss. If you had somewhere around 400 health like me when you do this level, the trick to beating the devil is an invincibility potion and fire scroll.

In all, the absolute hardest part of this level (unless you changed the javascript to give you a crap load of candy to convert to health) is wave one. Once you're through wave one, you're completely in the clear. You don't even need to worry about pressing i or k at that point.

Comment: turtle potions are *hella* expensive tho.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to use a completely different approach that `didn't use invuln pots` to get through hell.  To beat it, I needed:

1. health potions
2. one teleport scroll
3. 6 imp invocation scrolls
4. fire scroll

First, you have to get through the first wave of demons. As you work your way through the demons, fight through a spiked wall that spawns ghosts in the next wave (top two or bottom two lanes).

As often as you have an available cooldown from here out, take a health pot.  They're so cheap, anyway.

Once teleported back by the `*`, send out an imp on each available scroll cooldown.  You may only get 3 out before you bump into the imps at the front.  Teleport back, send out two more imps to make a conga line, as shown in the picture.

*(Side note, the teleport and more imps are not required, depending on how successfully you got through the first wave of demons and how many more cooldowns of HP pots you need)*

The reason for this line is as the imps slowly get through the second wall and the second teleporter, you have more time to pop pots, ensuring you're at full health.  As the imps break through, you're teleported to the start of the lane, send out one imp (or more!) and take on devil and slaughter him with the fire scroll.

Note:  I realize 680 HP might be more than many are taking on the devil with, but this was one way to defeat the Devil **without invuln pots**.

[image]

Comment: I found an Acid Rain scroll tremendously useful to clear out the Fireballs in the third wave, while imps died and I took damage.

Comment: If you go through this approach, you get to the devil before FBL waves even start.

Answer (score 2):

So you don't have to fight many creatures to get through Hell, the key is that you should *dodge out of the way* at any opportunity, and slowly move forward as a result. The first wave is easy like this, the second is harder as you're effectively pinned by the Ghosts on the outside (ghosts are evil), and must deal with the banshees in the middle.

Save an invulnerability potion for the final wave where you can't dodge, you should get through ok. The devil boss is actually less of a challenge than the dragon at the end of it all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody has suggested using trees yet.  I tried putting a tree in front of myself on at least one wave, and all of the enemies in that row just piled up behind it.  I waited for the rush of monsters to go past, and then it was smooth sailing to the end of the row.  I think some more monsters spawn in a wave after the first one is gone by, but by the time you reach the end it should be just beginning so you're mostly in the clear.

In terms of beating the DEV, I have no idea.

EDIT: it looks like the first wave is continuous, so this won't work.  Works on one of them, at least... I'll try to figure it out when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

You know, the sword of summoning sucks, and it's even weaker than a chocolate sword, so I suggest that next time you should get the fire sword. It's the best. Use I / K to move around to the places where the demons are thinnest.

Answer (score 0):

For the devils, I dodge out of their way, trying to weave past them as best as I can, and using invulnerability if in danger to reposition myself. For the ghost waves, additionally to summoning (imp of otherwise), I've found earthquake works amazingly well, cllearing the whole row you're on. You can us it twice before they catch up, then invulnerability should get you through to the end.

Answer (score -1):

so, first you should start with about 500 health.
make sure you have the unicorn horn (you will find it in castles keep)
and an invunurable potion.
health potions are optional.
so on the first wave, avoid any as possible. use major health potions if nessassary. then, destroy 1 wall.
now on round 2, ONLY go to ghosts because the unicorn horn will protect you from dieing. again, use heal potions if needed.
then destroy a deeper layer of wall. same as 3rd wave, go to only ghosts. then, use a invunurable potion at the demon himself. prey that you win. and if you have a good enough sword, you will win. 
hope this helps!